# Creating Dataframe with numpy array with index and columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array with the following shape:

```
numpy_x.shape
(9982, 26)
```

I want turn this numpy to dataframe:

```
x_new_df = pd.DataFrame(numpy_x)
```

And my new dataframe is:

```
x_new_df
```

[image]

How to can I generate the dataframe with index and columns names?

Comment: If need custom columns or index use `x_new_df = pd.DataFrame(numpy_x, index=idx, columns=cols)`, `idx` and `cols` are lists or 1d numpy arrays with same  size as `numpy_x.shape`

Comment: Hi @jezrael thanks for the edition and answer comment, but I get `NameError: name 'idx' is not defined`, Should I define some equvalence to `idx` and `cols` or their values are accesed by default?

Comment: OK, so what is problem? Need some another columns names and index like default?

Comment: My original dataset have some column names, and I want include them when I turn the numpy array to dataframe, here the columns of my original dataset https://cldup.com/0mzvGznzV3-3000x3000.png then I've filled the missing values and the output that I get is a numpy array, this numpy array I want translate to dataframe, but with the column names. Currently I cannot get the column names when I translate it.

Comment: Is possible extrcat columns names to list or 1d numpy array?

Comment: Yes, is possible

Comment: Super, the use `x_new_df = pd.DataFrame(numpy_x, columns=cols)` where `cols` are list or `numpy 1d array`

Comment: @jezrael I don't understand what list type should be cols

Comment: it is plain list, L= ['a','b','c']